# What is the $scenario variable in Codeception?

Tags: php, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am learning to use Codeception. In the [Writing a Sample Scenario](http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Writing-a-Sample-Scenario) documentation, one mentions a `$scenario` variable.

Say I implement a `MyAcceptanceTester` class, is this some kind of parameters variable I can use to control the behavior of my Actor? Or is this a *reserved* variable in the Codeception paradigm? If so, how does it work?

My testing need is the following: I need to run the same sequence of actions on several domain names. It's a case where one domain name is used per language, but all code is in the same code base and is delivered by the same Apache server. Each domain may have its own PHP code, but also shares common code with other domains. Hence, Codeception testing code will be located in the unique code base.

I was thinking about passing each URL/URI to test in `MyAcceptanceTester` via the `$scenario` variable. Is this the right way to proceed? Or should I subclass `MyAcceptanceTester` for each domain, because `$scenario` is reserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$scenario` variable on your `*Cept.php` file actually an variable assigned to construct the `AcceptanceTester` class. To inspect how it's work you may open `AcceptanceTester` class file in `test/_support/AcceptanceTester.php`. If you see `AcceptanceTester` class is extended from `Codeception\Actor` class. Follow this [source](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/4.0/src/Codeception/Actor.php) to read how `$scenario` variable used by the `Actor`.

About your case.

> I need to run the same sequence of actions on several domain names.

You can implement a technic called `StepObject` ([documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#StepObjects)). So the test for each website will extend from `StepObjet` that you recently created.

Hope it helps.